# Add WYSIWYG editor to Prestashop 1.6.X module smarty template form

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.6, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I am doing a custom module in Prestashop 1.6.X. In my module I have form which is made in smarty. I want to add WYSIWYG editor in that smarty form. So can someone tell me how to add WYSIWYG editor to smarty template form? Any help or suggestion will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You have many solution to indicate if element in your Form have wysiwyg editor. If you use helperform you can use this solution :

**Solution backoffice / use helper form**

```
$fields_form[0]['form'] = array (
            'input' => array (
                array (
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => $this->l ( 'Your field:' ),
                    'name' => 'pdf_content',
                    'autoload_rte' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'lang' => true,
                    'rows' => 10,
                    'cols' => 100,
                    'hint' => $this->l ( 'Invalid characters:' ).' <>;=#{}'
                ),
****
$helper = new HelperForm ();
****
$helper->generateForm ( $fields_form )
```

**Second solution in your template :**

Example in yourmodule.php function getContent

```
public function getContent()
    {

$iso = $this->context->language->iso_code;
                                $this->tpl_vars['iso'] = file_exists(_PS_CORE_DIR_.'/js/tiny_mce/langs/'.$iso.'.js') ? $iso : 'en';
                                $this->tpl_vars['path_css'] = _THEME_CSS_DIR_;
                                $this->tpl_vars['ad'] = __PS_BASE_URI__.basename(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_);
                                $this->tpl_vars['tinymce'] = true;

                                $this->context->controller->addJS(_PS_JS_DIR_.'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js');
                                $this->context->controller->addJS(_PS_JS_DIR_.'admin/tinymce.inc.js');
```

**in your smarty template file :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iso = '{$iso|escape:'quotes':'UTF-8'}';
    var pathCSS = '{$smarty.const._THEME_CSS_DIR_|escape:'quotes':'UTF-8'}';
    var ad = '{$ad|escape:'quotes':'UTF-8'}';
    $(document).ready(function(){


            tinySetup({
                editor_selector :"autoload_rte",
                relative_urls : false,
                plugins : "colorpicker link image paste pagebreak table contextmenu filemanager table code media autoresize textcolor fullpage",
                extended_valid_elements : "em[class|name|id],html,head"
            });


    });
</script>

<textarea name="content_html" class="rte autoload_rte rte autoload_rte">your text rich</textarea>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. I know about the helper form but I want that in smarty template as I am using custom form.
Thanks

Comment: is there any js plugin for tinySetup ?

Comment: Yes you must add this $this->context->controller->addJS(_PS_JS_DIR_.'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js');
                                $this->context->controller->addJS(_PS_JS_DIR_.'admin/tinymce.inc.js'); Let me know

Comment: PS_JS_DIR is not working. Although I have tried to use hard coded link to the js its working but PS_JS_DIR is not working? Can you help me in that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99798/discussion-between-timactive-and-newuser).

Comment: You can also see https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/251055-solved-saving-text-as-html-in-configuration-table/?do=findComment&comment=1248220